# How to add a Custom Openshot Blender Template?

Tags: python, video-editor, blender, animations, openshot

After Creating the appropriate files and structure as listed

```
./blender/custom.xml
./blender/blend/custom.blend
./blender/scripts/custom.py
./blender/icons/custom.png
```

and placed in the location 
`/usr/share/pyshared/openshot/blender`

No option is available in Openshot to use the custom template.

How to do you add it to the Openshot GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the forums on the Openshot website this thread was found:

http://openshotusers.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=821

Where in it mentions the problem is that the files are not directly access rather a symbolic link is used from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openshot/blender`

In my case it was required to create symbolic links from:

`/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openshot/blender`